# why sklearn.metrics.mutual_info_score can get mutual information without a joint distribution?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

The definition of mutual information is :

[image]

[wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_information#:%7E:text=Mutual%20information%20can%20be%20equivalently%20expressed%20as%3A)

Apperantly if they are independent, `p(x,y)=p(x)p(y)`, and then according to another form, `I(x,y)=0` , so there must be a dependence.

[image]

But as we know, we can't just get a joint distribution from 2 dependent margin distribution.

I can give an example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/77334/how-does-one-generally-find-a-joint-distribution-function-or-density-from-marg)

So is it a right way to do so ? Can we get `P(i,j)` directly? Is there some strong hypothesis here?

[image]

The example in sklearn

```
from sklearn import metrics
labels_true = [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]
labels_pred = [0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2]

metrics.adjusted_mutual_info_score(labels_true, labels_pred)
```

and we can easily get `h(labels_true)` and `h(labels_pred)`, how we get `p(labels_true, labels_pred）`？